# Select matching array with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

hotdeal:

```
{ "property" : "ATL-D406" }
```

translation:

```
{ "property" : "ATL-D406", "language" : "gb", "txt": [{"aaa":"hi", "bbb":"bye"}] }
{ "property" : "ATL-D406", "language" : "ru", "txt": [{"aaa":"priviet", "bbb":"baka"}] } 
{ "property" : "ATL-D406", "language" : "cn", "txt": [{"aaa":"??", "bbb":"??"}] }
```

Current result:

```
{ "property":"ATL-D406", "language":[ "gb", "ru", "cn" ] }
```

What I would like:

```
{ "property":"ATL-D406", "language":"gb", "aaa":"hi", "bbb":"bye" }
```

I cannot understand why my $elemMatch is not working, shouldn't it isolate that particular element in the result from "translation"?

Also once I got it to only take the "gb" language, how do I project "aaa" and "bbb" without them being inside an array?  I tried $resolve but then I get no data at all. Can you $resolve an array in an array? ($resolve "txt")?

```
db.hotdeal.aggregate([ 
    { '$match': {} },
    { '$lookup': { 
        from: 'translation', 
        localField: 'property', 
        foreignField: 'property', 
        as: 'translations' 
    } },

    { '$match': 
        { 'translations': 
            { '$elemMatch': { 'language': 'gb' } }
        } 
    }, 

    { '$project': { 
        _id: 0, 
        property: 1, 
        language: '$translations.language'
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the wrong operation. You want [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), and also [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) by the look of it. The [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator is a "query" operation for *"selection of data"*, and is not used to "filter" array content.

```js
db.hotdeal.aggregate([ 
    { '$match': {} },
    { '$lookup': { 
        'from': 'translation', 
        'localField': 'property', 
        'foreignField': 'property', 
        'as': 'translations' 
    } },
    { '$project': { 
        '_id': 0, 
        'property': 1, 
        'translation': {
         '$arrrayElemAt': [
           { '$map': {
             'input': {
               '$filter': {
                 'input': '$translations'
                 'as': 't',
                 'cond': { '$eq': [ '$$t.language', 'gb' ] }
               },
             },
             'as': 't',
             'in': {
               'language': '$$t',
               'aaa': { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$$t.txt.aaa', 0 ] },
               'bbb': { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$$t.txt.bbb', 0 ] }
             }
           }},
           0
         ]
       }
    }},
    { '$project': {
      'property': 1,
      'language': '$translation.language',
      'aaa': '$translation.aaa',
      'bbb': '$translation.bbb'
    }}
])
```

I generally find that these sort of *"trival"* structural changes are best handled in "client code" rather than mangling through the aggregation framework anyway.

So simply do the "join" and then let the "client" process the alteration:

```js
db.hotdeal.aggregate([ 
    { '$match': {} },
    { '$lookup': { 
        'from': 'translation', 
        'localField': 'property', 
        'foreignField': 'property', 
        'as': 'translations' 
    } }
]).forEach( doc => {
  let translation = doc.translations.find( t => t.language === 'gb' );
  doc.language = translation.language;
  doc.aaa = translation.txt[0].aaa;
  doc.bbb = translation.txt[0].bbb;

  delete doc.translations;
  delete doc._id;
  printjson(doc);
});
```

So that is doing the same thing, yet is far less obtuse.

Comment: Hi Neil.  Interesting but a quite complex way to do it.  Are you sure that you cannot use $elemMatch inside a $match operation on the data you  got from the $lookup? I believe I have done so before.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard Read it all. `$elemMatch` would only "confirm" that the document has the matching property in an element of the array which resulted from `$lookup`. It **does not remove it**. That is what you are asking. What I also conclude when you read everything is that the "complex" operation is completely unnecessary. Falls under the category of *"Just because you can do it, does not mean you should"*. The *swiss army chainsaw* and all that. Don't overuse aggregation functions when you are not "aggregating".

Comment: Neil, I just managed to do it like this....  argh! I cannot format code here - let me post it as an answer so you can see it.

Comment: Neil have a look at my answer - it actually gave the desired result.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard `$unwind` is not an efficient way of processing this. It does work, but there is a large cost with large collections and arrays

Comment: Ok - its so easy to do with unwind, and I do have some very large collections with 2-3 unwinds inside where I only need a few fields in the project.  So I think you are right, that it can slow down things a lot.

Comment: your example with the `forEach` at the end. This cannot be tested in S3T or Robomongo right?  You hare to put this in your nodejs controller? or can you send such code to Mongodb to execute?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard Any JavaScript environment will do. I have shorter ES6 arrow notation there that is compatible with the latest release mongo shell. If the JavaScript environment ( such as robomongo ) does not support ES6 then you just replace the things like `doc => {` with `function(doc) {` instead.

Comment: I use Studio3T and it really do not like fat-arrow and several other things. Do you just use the raw mongo shell?  Anyway in this case where I have very little data, the unwind did the trick. But you taught me to immediately clean/manipulate the data in javascript before delivering the result, this is very powerful because it will enable my controllers to deliver very clean data to angular.  Thank you for teaching me how to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
db.hotdeal.aggregate([ 
    { '$match': {} },
    { '$lookup': { 
        from: 'translation', 
        localField: 'property', 
        foreignField: 'property', 
        as: 'translations' 
    } },

    { '$unwind': '$translations' },

    { '$match': { 'translations.language': 'gb' } }, 

    { '$project': { 
        _id: 0, 
        property: 1, 
        language: '$translations.language',
        aaa: '$translations.txt.aaa',
        bbb: '$translations.txt.bbb'
    }}
])
```